# Why setting mutiple GPUs in keras , only one is running?

Tags: keras, gpu, tf.keras, training-data, multi-gpu

Here's api I am using and is refered from office website[keras Multi-GPU](https://keras.io/guides/distributed_training/)

I use mirrored strategy:

```
cross_device_ops = tf.distribute.HierarchicalCopyAllReduce()
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(["device:GPU:%d" % i for i in range(2)],cross_device_ops=cross_device_ops)  #,"/gpu:1","/gpu:0"]
print('Number of devices: {}'.format(strategy.num_replicas_in_sync))  # out 2

# Open a strategy scope.
with strategy.scope():
    model = UNet()
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001), loss=dice_coef_loss, metrics=[dice_coef])
```

Comment: For example, I give a push to GPUs  and  one even high to 98% and the other is still 0% from beginning to end

Comment: The is the `fit()` method inside the `with` statement?

Comment: @ML_Engine outside, after the question centent,  

   train_data

    validation_data
    model_checkpoint 
    model.fit_generator()

Comment: Try putting `fit()` inside the with statement

Comment: @ML_Engine I just tried your suggestion, and it sill does not work. But Many thanks  for your reply .